# Lazy evaluations of data structures

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I'm reading about lazy evaluations in haskell and have a question. For example we have following computations:

```
Prelude> let x = 1 + 1 :: Int
Prelude> let y = (x,x)
```

And after getting value of `x`:

```
Prelude> :sprint x
x = _
```

It's unevaluated. Ok, now let's get value of y:

```
Prelude> :sprint y
y = (_,_)
```

It is unevaluated too, because `y` depends on `x and it's unevaluated`. Now let's try the same example but without `::Int`:

```
Prelude> let x = 1 + 1
Prelude> let y = (x, x)
Prelude> :sprint y
y = _
```

Why `y` value is `_` instead `(_, _)` when we're trying without `::Int`?

I see that they have different types:

```
Prelude> let x = 1 + 1
Prelude> :t x
x :: Num a => a
Prelude> let x = 1 + 1 :: Int
Prelude> :t x
x :: Int
```

But why values of `y` depends on it?

Thank you.

Comment: Now for the really fun part, with `x` having type `Num a => a`, what happens after you fully evaluate both `x` and `y`?  What happens to their `:sprint` representation?

Comment: @bheklilr, yes, very interesting. I made: `seq` for `x` and `y`, they prints values, but :sprint prints `_`

Comment: What does it even mean to "evaluate" `x` when its type is `Num a => a`?  How does the compiler know what to do with it?  How is it able to say that `x`'s value is `2` when it doesn't know which implementation of `+` to use?  I could implement my own newtype around `Int` that has `+` defined as `(MyInt x) + (MyInt y) = MyInt (x - y)`, so what is GHC doing here to be able to print that `x` has value `2`?

Comment: @bheklilr ah, now I partially understand, but why if I typed `y` in ghci it prints (2, 2), but `:sprint y` prints `y = _`. How does it know what's implementation `+` to apply when we just print `y` in ghci?

Comment: It can't possibly know which instance of `Num` to use to print it out, right?  So what do you think it's doing instead?  What would you do if you were writing GHCi and wanted to be able to print out values of type `Num a => a` with the assumption that no one would ever be evil enough to define `+` as `-`?  I know I'd just pick a sane default to "evaluate" it, but not actually store that result in the variable's memory location

Comment: @bheklilr yes, thought about the same after writing last comment. Many thanks for explanation. Can you write an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: btw: it seems strange that `y` should show `_` I think this is a typo? (It's not happening on my GHCi and I would really wonder as it should evaluate to WHNF)

Comment: @CarstenKönig That happens in my GHC.  If `y :: Num a => (a, a)`, then it can't evaluate `y` even to WHNF (I think?), so it's thunk is `_`, not `(_, _)`.  Do you perchance have the `MonomorphismRestriction` on?  I haven't tested with it on since I configured GHCi to disable it by default.

Comment: I did not disable it (knowingly) so yes it might be on - but why should it not be able to eval it to the `(,)` constructor? (I guess I have to reread this stuff and think a bit about it)

Comment: indeed you are right - if I disable the restriction it will eval to `_` ... interesting ... Haskell/GHCi never fails to show me something new each day ;)

Comment: ok ... I think I got it - removing the restriction the type-system cannot know (or don't seem to know looking only on the types) if the first and second part of the tuple are really the same types (doh - but this matches the description from here http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) - so it will stop right there and indeed: `:t y` yields `y :: (Num t, Num t1) => (t, t1)` - thanks @0xAX for this question - made my day :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening is that when you've specified `x` to have the type `Num a => a`, the compiler can't possibly know which instance of `Num` to use when performing `1 + 1`.  What it does instead is use defaulting.  GHC defines default types for certain typeclasses so that when there's no possible way to determine what concrete type to use it can still give meaningful results without raising errors.  So when you see

```
> let x :: Num a => a
|     x = 1 + 1
> x
2
> :sprint x
x = _
```

This is because GHCi chooses `Integer` as its default type for `Num`, but when it performs this operation it doesn't store the result in `x`'s memory location, since there isn't a way to know if that is even the correct answer.  This is why you see `x = _` from `:sprint`, it hasn't actually evaluated `x :: Num a => a`, it's evaluated `x :: Integer`.  You can even mess with this default yourself:

```
> newtype MyInt = MyInt Int deriving (Eq)
>
> instance Show MyInt where
|     show (MyInt i) = show i
> instance Num MyInt where
|     (MyInt x) + (MyInt y) = MyInt (x - y)
|     fromInteger = MyInt . fromInteger
>
> default (MyInt)
> x
0
```

So now we've said that `1 + 1 = 0`!  Keep in mind that you will probably never have a use for this functionality of GHC, but it's good to know about.

Comment: btw: on my system GHCi will set `x` to `2 :: Integer` after evaluating it!